# Hibernate create relation without relational table

Tags: mysql, hibernate, join, orm, hibernate-mapping

Is it possible to map hibernate entities without using another table that is mapping them ?

When I create @OneToMany and @ManyToOne relation between 2 entities, hibernate always creates another table in the database to map the relation, I would like to map 2 entities directly using column in the mapped entity like this:

[image]

"InstalledApp" entity:

```
@OneToMany (fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity=InstalledAppPort.class, mappedBy = "id")
private List<InstalledAppPort> ports;
```

"InstalledAppPort" entity:

```
@ManyToOne (targetEntity=InstalledApp.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "iappId")
private InstalledApp iapp;
```

When using the code above, the list is always empty and I do not know why. Technically this mapping should work but it is not. No exception thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using:

```
@OneToMany (fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity=InstalledAppPort.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "iappId", referencedColumnName = "id")
private List<InstalledAppPort> ports;
```